# react-table custom sortType not able to sort columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm trying to define a custom sorting function in a column def using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) . However, when using this custom function the table columns are not sortable. I think there is something incorrect with my syntax.

This works (I am able to sort the columns)

```
sortType: column.accessor === "myColumnId" ? "basic" : "alphanumeric"
```

This does **not** work (I am not able to sort any columns):

```
sortType: getWoSortType,
```

where `getWoSortType` looks like this:

```
// sort types
export const getWoSortType = (rowA, rowB, id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case "isolationPlans":
      return "basic";
    default:
      return "alphanumeric";
  }
};
```

I have tried debugging `getWoSortType` and everything looks correct, i. e. the values are defined and the correct cases are being reached. Why does it not work using this other syntax?